# Python lambda call function with None output

Tags: python, lambda

I want to realize something like use `lambda` to call a function which has an output of None or list and if it is a list, then get the first value.

```
lambda x: func(x,args)[0] if func(x,args) is not None else None
```

However, in this function it seems to need to call the function twice to find out whether it is None. Of course I can just write the code using try or conditional statements:

```
def function(x):
    try: 
        return func(x,args)[0]
    except (IndexError,TypeError):
        return None
```

or just change the output of `func`. But I am still curious about if there are some methods to call the function only once with `lambda`.

Comment: At the very least only catch the `IndexError` and `TypeError` exceptions that your code can throw, not *everything else* (including memory errors and keyboard interrupts).

Comment: Why not `list = func(x,args); lambda x: list[0] if list else None`

Comment: @yinnonsanders No, because then it takes 2 lines, not one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This'll do:

```
lambda x: (func(x, args) or [None])[0]
```